# req.login is not logging the user

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

What I am trying to do is use ajax to send a post request to the server, and make sure that post request does not refresh the page (using e.preventDefault). On the server I want to check if the username or email is taken and if it is not taken, then automatically log the user in and then refresh the page. The issue is when I call req.login and submit the data to be logged in it doesn't seem to be working but the page still refreshes. Any ideas?

```
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
var userDetails = User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password1, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
});

User.findOne({
    $or: [{
        'username': req.body.username
    }, {
            'email': req.body.email
        }]
}, function (err, user) {
    if (user) {
        if (allClients.indexOf(req.body.socket)) {
            if (user.username === req.body.username) {
                io.to(req.body.socket).emit('userInfo', 'That username is already in use.');
            } else {
            }
            if (user.email === req.body.email) {
                io.to(req.body.socket).emit('userInfo', 'That email is already in use.');
            } else {
            }
        } else {
            console.log('timeout error 822')
        }
    } else {
        req.login(userDetails, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                userDetails.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.redirect('/');
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});
});
```

Here is where I make the ajax post request. As you can see I am preventing the form submit to refresh the page, but if the form is succesful it will submit.

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/signup',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your 'already taken' messages are considered success by your API.
You can either throw an error on those cases and `catch` with `$.ajax` or set a different response and read `data` on `success`.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine when I remove e.preventDefault from the ajax call. Is there a way I can tell that ajax request from the server to stop the e.preventDefault function and continue with the redirect('/') after the data is saved to the mongo store?

Comment: I don't think that would be the best approach. Add a `.error()` (or `.fail()` depending on which version of jQ you are using) to check what you are getting back. Or console log `data` on `success`...

Comment: How would I throw an error to the ajax request in this scenario, when I emit to the client?

Comment: How are you handling your http responses? I mean, status codes.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a complete beginner at node js. I don't really know what to say. I am trying what I wrote again and it looks like most of the time when I  post the form req.user exist and everything works fine, but sometimes req.user is undefined. I will look into this more. Thanks for the help.